# Why SQL Anywhere16 32-bit odbc driver won't connect to 32- bit application on release mode?

Tags: odbc, sqlanywhere

I have tried to connect *SQL Anywhere 16 ODBC driver(32-bit)* in our 32- bit application, it wont connect in release mode. But it works fine in Debug mode.

Comment: (1) Please add details. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (2) Guessing you're on Windows, using Visual Studio, [this article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin) may help.

Comment: @TallTed : Thank you so much. Yes I am using Visual Studio 2017 and also SQLAnywhere 32-bit driver. But driver configuration window didn't open for me in release mode but it works fine in debug mode.

Comment: Are you sure you've told VS2017 to build for deployment as a 32-bit app?